# Working with file system from Generic Kernel Extension (macOS)

Tags: c, macos, file-io, macos-sierra, kernel-extension

For example, i want to create a file named "example.txt" and write "Hello world!" into it. In theory, I can write something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <mach/mach_types.h>

kern_return_t examplekext_start(kmod_info_t * ki, void *d);
kern_return_t examplekext_stop(kmod_info_t *ki, void *d);

kern_return_t examplekext_start(kmod_info_t * ki, void *d)
{
    char const *hw = "Hello world!";
    FILE *xmpl = fopen("/example.txt", "w");
    int *s = fwrite(hw, strlen(hw), 1, xmpl);
    if (s == 1) return KERN_SUCCESS;
    else return KERN_FAILURE;
}

kern_return_t examplekext_stop(kmod_info_t *ki, void *d)
{
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}
```

But, if I will try to build & run something like that, I will get an error: "stdio.h file not found". So, the question is how can I do that? Is there an another lib for working with file system or something like that? Or that is impossible to do from a kernel extension?

Comment: The answer for this Q is already replied in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13209594/351305. As I understand you are not supposed to be doing any arbitrary disk I/O.