# Passing CFDictionary via IOKIt command

Tags: macos, registry, iokit, kernel-extension, xnu

I'm looking for a universal method to configure parameters from userspace  agent to kernel since there is no Mac equivalent to windows registry where driver can directly access any key in this table using `ZwQueryValueKey` command.

Therefore, I'd like to pass a dynamic list of variables through `CFDictionary`.

In `IOConnectCallMethod` there's a way to pass input pointer, but the question is if I can pass a `CFDictionary` or `CFDictionaryRef` instead of just a simple struct.

I saw that there are some IOkit commands that enable you to pass CFDictionaryRef directly, such as `IOServiceGetMatchingService` but these are not intended for the driver module but for the entity that manages the drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the I/O Kit property mechanism to exchange plist-like data between user space and kernel space. For setting them from userspace, you'll want to use one or more of the following IOKitLib functions:

- `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty`
- `IORegistryEntrySetCFProperties`
- `IOConnectSetCFProperty`
- `IOConnectSetCFProperties`

On the kernel side, your IOService or IOUserClient subclass should override the `virtual IOReturn setProperties( OSObject * properties );` function. Don't forget to treat any data received as potentially hostile, so make sure you check for `nullptr`s, use `OSDynamicCast()` when expecting concrete `OSData`/`OSNumber`/`OSString`/`OSArray`/etc. objects, and sanitise the data itself.

Note that `setProperties()` does not automatically update the properties of the `IORegistryEntry` object, you still need to call `this->setProperty()` for every property key/value key after it's been checked.

Apple provides [some basic high-level documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_IOKitLib_API/AH_IOKitLib_API.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000380-TPXREF114) for this mechanism too.